# Open link in iframe and then open another link in same window

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this code:

```
echo '<a href="case_util.php?status=green&adr=' . $adr.  '" rel="nofollow" onClick="javascript:document.location(create.php)" target="second">Send map to 2nd screen</a>';
```

Id like to be able to press this link, which opens the case_util.php in another iframe and then goes to another link in its own iframe.

Sort of like a refresh/going back. However, it is a form, and pressing back retains the data in the form. I dont want this data in the form, hence I'd like it to navigate to the page.

Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure I understand this correctly, are you trying to submit a form by clicking on a link ? Why not use a proper form control (submit button) ? Also, is NOT having the data in the form when pressing the back button after a submit the only thing you're after ? If so, there are more elegant (and correct) ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issues. document.location is not a function and is deprecated anyway.

Here is a better version

```
echo '<a href="case_util.php?status=green&adr=' . $adr.  '" rel="nofollow" onClick="window.location='create.php'" target="second">Send map to 2nd screen</a>';
```

or easier to read since you want the href in the iframe named second .

```
...?> <a href="case_util.php?status=green&adr=<?php echo $adr; ?>" rel="nofollow" target="second"
 onClick="window.location='create.php'" >Send map to 2nd screen</a>
```

Comment: Although correct, this doesn't answer the OP's question at all.

Comment: In what way does it not answer?

Answer (score 0):

Best answer:
Don't use iframes.

However if you are determined to use something as silly as an iframe, use something as silly as a meta redirect.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/"/>
```

;) seriously, just read about AJAX+jQuery instead:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/